# How to insert a child inside child and how to retrive all of its data on mongodb php?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId("56287878cae2aa280b00002b"),
     'name': 's',
     'description': '',
     'status': 'Inactive',
     'hasChild': '0',
     'created': '2015-10-22 11:17:36',
    }
```

I have created document for a main category as above,
Now, I am adding a child element for it with the following query.

```
                    $time = (string) time();
                    $subCategoryData = array('child.' . $time => $dataArr);
                    $condition = array('_id' => new \MongoId(trim($this->input->post('child'))));

    $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection(CATEGORY);

    $collection->update($condition,$subCategoryData)
```

While updating I assign unique id for each sub category through timestamp, as it will be unique.

```
 {
'_id': ObjectId("56287878cae2aa280b00002b"),
 'name': 's',
 'description': '',
 'status': 'Inactive',
 'hasChild': '1',
 'created': '2015-10-22 11:17:36',
 'child': {
    'key_1445492861': {
        'name': 'ss',
        'description': '',
        'status': 'Inactive',
        'updated_at': '2015-10-22 11:17:41',
        'parent': '56287878cae2aa280b00002b'
        },
        'key_1445492870': {
            'name': 'vv',
            'description': '',
            'status': 'Inactive',
            'updated_at': '2015-10-22 11:17:50',
            'parent': '56287878cae2aa280b00002b'
        }
    }
}
```

After inserting sub category as a child it does look like above. I struck with two things.
1. I have no idea how to insert child inside a child.
2. If child inserted inside a child, How can I retrieve all of its data by querying?
Give me an idea how to achieve it, If it's a long process to explain.
Thank you!

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-edit-update-and-delete-data-in-mongodb-with-codeigniter/